# TYPO3 PowerMail only shows default language in error messages

Tags: typo3

On my site where Danish is default language and English is second language, I have a PowerMail form.
But the error messages at mandatory fields will only show in default language, Danish.

Why?

Comment: Can you put the typoscript who manage the language please.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, the lang files for powermail errors comes from the jquery validation language file.
So, probably this file is not loaded.
Not an answer, but could give you a clue

Comment: That is a good clkue, but JQuery validation is set to 0 in the TypoScript. The form doens't check until you press Submit.